# How to set data retention time in DolphinDB?

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb, dolphindb

I would like to store device data in DolphinDB and keep data for 3 month. It is trouble to drop data manually by function dropPartition every 3 months. Can DolphinDB clear expired data automatically? Dose DolphinDB have retention policy like influxdb?

Answer (score 1):

DolphinDB has a function "setRetentionPolicy" for this purpose.

https://www.dolphindb.com/help/setRetentionPolicy.html